# Firefox get unique id of tabs for extension development

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm developing a Firefox extension, and I need get and work with unique id of tabs.

How I can do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can because of security measures.

Comment: Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser and see if that helps you. I don't think the tabs have id's but you can store a reference to a particular tab.

Answer (score 5):

If you use the [Firefox SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.14/dev-guide/tutorials/getting-started-with-cfx.html), you can get the id of the active tab by using:

```
var tabs = require('sdk/tabs');
var activeTabId = tabs.activeTab.id;
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the active Window Id of the firefox browser from the extension?

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution.
You can try this out.
The function below will return you a unique id of the current tab.

```
var get_current_tab_id = function()
        {
            var doc = gBrowser.contentDocument; //Gets the current document.
            var tab = null;
            var targetBrowserIndex = gBrowser.getBrowserIndexForDocument(doc);
            if (targetBrowserIndex != -1)
            tab = gBrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[targetBrowserIndex];
            else
            return(null);
            return(tab.linkedPanel);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out the documentation for `nsIWindowMediator`, which provides information and access to all open windows within Firefox.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIWindowMediator#getEnumerator

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to interact in any way with the open firefox tabs via javascript then the answer is that you cannot.

Comment: Sorry, I think you don't understand! I creat a firefox extensions!

Comment: Apologies. Your question and tags didn't mention anything about extension development.